# Select content (html) from button but not everyting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im stuck on a problem and I actually don't know what I am searchig for. I thought `filter` was it but doesn't look like.

Problem:
I have a button with following content

```
<button type="button"
        id="myButton" 
        class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
        data-toggle="dropdown" 
        aria-expanded="false">
    Group ...
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

I have a second button, if I click it, I want to select the html content of the first button.

```
$('#buttonTwo').on('click', function(){
    var group = $('#myButton').html();
    alert(group);
});
```

At the moment it also selects the `<span>` but I don't want it. Can anyone may help me to

only select `Group ...` ?

Comment: `var group = $('#myButton').text();`?

Comment: god, things can be so easy ^^ thank you very much. make a post and ill accept it and vote up. i guess i'm thinking to complicated all the time :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use jQuery's `.text()` function you'll omit the HTML:

```
var group = $('#myButton').text();
```

Comment: As it was already mentioned by Runcorn, things can go wrong if `<span>` has text.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `.text()` but if the `span` happens to have text in it then it will be wrong. So instead you could clone the button and then remove the `span` from it so you could use the .`html()` or the `text()` like

```
var clonedButton = $('#myButton').clone();
$('span', clonedButton ).remove();
alert(clonedButton.html());
```

And here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwwspeev/) for you...

Comment: actually the span will never have text :) its bootstrap and is used for a caret image :) +1 because you are right but i accept the other answere because that was the first helping hint.

Comment: And [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwwspeev/1/) without cloning. Well, without jQuery at all. And works not only with `<span>`s. But it is not short code, that's for sure.